Model Form Data is not Visible When i try to update the model in django
so this is the view :
def update_ticket(response,ticket_title):
  ticket = get_object_or_404(TicketsModel, title=ticket_title)
  ticket_form = AddTicketsForm(response.POST or None,instance=ticket,assigned_by=response.user)
  if 'return' in response.POST:
    return redirect('home', type_user=response.session.get('type_user'))
  if ticket_form.is_valid():
    ticket.ticket_creation_date = datetime.now()
    ticket_form.save()
    return redirect('home', type_user=response.session.get('type_user'))

return render(response, "template/testapp/update_ticket.html", {'ticket_title': ticket.title, 'ticket_form': ticket_form})

the problem is , when i render the form , i dont see the data inside of the inputs , but if i delete the 'response.POST' in the AddTicketsForm() , i can see the data but i cant update nothing
here is the html content
<h2>Update Ticket</h2>
        <form action="{% url 'update_ticket' ticket_title=ticket_title %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ ticket_form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" name="save" id="regDirect" >Save</button>
            <button type="submit" name="return">Return</button>
        <form/>


To display the current data in the form fields while also being able to update the data, you should use the request.method property to conditionally include request.POST when the form is being submitted, and exclude it when rendering the form for the first time.
Try this view:
def update_ticket(response, ticket_title):
    ticket = get_object_or_404(TicketsModel, title=ticket_title)
    ticket_form = AddTicketsForm(instance=ticket, assigned_by=response.user, **response.POST** if response.method == 'POST' else None)

    if 'return' in response.POST:
        return redirect('home', type_user=response.session.get('type_user'))

    if ticket_form.is_valid():
        ticket.ticket_creation_date = datetime.now()
        ticket_form.save()
        return redirect('home', type_user=response.session.get('type_user'))

    return render(response, "template/testapp/update_ticket.html", {'ticket_title': ticket.title, 'ticket_form': ticket_form})

So now, your AddTicketsForm will have the request.POST data when the form is submitted, and it will not include request.POST when rendering the form for the first time, which allows you to see the data inside the inputs.
When the form is submitted, the request.POST will be included, and the is_valid() method will handle the update accordingly.

still the same problem , when i delete the 'response.POST if response.method == 'POST' else None' i can see my instance details , but if i include it i only see a post empty form

done i fixed the problem ,  it was that i used button inside form to redirect me to the update page and then same button inside the update page , like i should have used 'a' tag to redirect not a button inside a form
